# How to configure monopolistic FIFO application queue in YARN?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I need to disable parallel execution of YARN applications in hadoop cluster. Now, YARN has default settings, so several jobs can run in parallel. I see no advantages of this, because both jobs run slower.

I found this setting `yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications` which limits maximum number of applications, but it affects both submitted and running apps (as stated in docs). I'd like to keep submitted apps in queue until current running application is not finished. How can this be done?

Comment: How many different users would be submitting the jobs?

Comment: @franklinsijo 2 or 3 users, at most 3 jobs submitted at the same time

Answer (score 7):

**1) Change Scheduler to `FairScheduler`**

Hadoop distributions use `CapacityScheduler` by default (Cloudera uses `FairScheduler` as default Scheduler). Add this property to `yarn-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler</value>
</property>
```

**2) Set `default` Queue**

Fair Scheduler creates a queue per user. I.E., if three different users submit jobs then three individual queues will be created and the resources will be shared among the three queues. Disable it by adding this property in `yarn-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.user-as-default-queue</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
```

This assures that all the jobs go into a single **`default`** queue.

**3) Restrict Maximum Applications**

Now that the job queue has been limited to one `default` queue. Restrict the maximum number of applications to **`1`** that can be run in that queue.

Create a file named `fair-scheduler.xml` under the `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` and add these entries

```
<allocations>
   <queueMaxAppsDefault>1</queueMaxAppsDefault>
</allocations>
```

Also, add this property in `yarn-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.allocation.file</name>
  <value>$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/fair-scheduler.xml</value>
</property>
```

Restart `YARN` services after adding these properties.

---

On submitting multiple applications, the application `ACCEPTED` first will be considered as the Active application and the remaining will be queued as Pending applications. These pending applications will continue to be in `ACCEPTED` state until the `RUNNING` application is `FINISHED`. The Active application will be allowed to utilise all the available resources.

**Reference:** [Hadoop: Fair Scheduler](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html)

Comment: nice answer, I will try it soon

Comment: We haven't tried it yet but it feels that approach is correct. I'll accept the answer when we check it.

Comment: Okay @Adam. Comment here if you get any issues 

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding about your question. I see, the above code line/setting only may not help you. Can you check below code with your existing setup, it may give you some solution.

```
<allocations>
  <defaultQueueSchedulingPolicy>fair</defaultQueueSchedulingPolicy>

  <queue name="<<Your Queue Name>>"
    <weight>40</weight>
    <schedulingPolicy>fifo</schedulingPolicy>
  </queue>

  <queue name=<<Your Queue Name>>>
    <weight>60</weight>
    <queue name=<<Your Queue Name>> />
    <queue name=<<Your Queue Name>> />
  </queue>

  <queuePlacementPolicy>
    <rule name="specified" create="false" />
    <rule name="primaryGroup" create="false" />
    <rule name="default" queue=<<Your Queue Name>> />
  </queuePlacementPolicy>
</allocations>
```

Comment: Can you give a link where you found these settings? There's no explanation how it works, I can't just blindly push them to cluster

Comment: Adam, The link here : https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html -- I'm referring book : Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, 4th Edition by Tom White. Chapter-4