# Running submitted job sequentially in Google Cloud Dataproc

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I created Google Dataproc cluster with 2 workers using `n1-standard-4` VMs for master and workers.

I want to submit jobs on a given cluster and all jobs should run sequentially (like on AWS EMR), i.e., if first job is in running state then upcoming job goes to pending state, after completing first job, second job starts running.

I tried with submitting jobs on cluster but it run all jobs in parallel - no jobs went to pending state.

Is there any configuration that I can set in Dataproc cluster so all jobs will run sequentially?

*Updated following files* :

**/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml**

```
  <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.user-as-default-queue</name>
      <value>false</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.allocation.file</name>
      <value>/etc/hadoop/conf/fair-scheduler.xml</value>
   </property>
```

**/etc/hadoop/conf/fair-scheduler.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<allocations>
   <queueMaxAppsDefault>1</queueMaxAppsDefault>
</allocations>
```

After that restart services using this command `systemctl restart hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager` the above changes on master node. But still job running in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dataproc tries to execute submitted jobs in parallel if resources are available.

To achieve sequential execution you may want to use some orchestration solution, either [Dataproc Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/workflows/overview) or [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/).

Alternatively, you may want to [configure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49693693/3227693) [YARN Fair Scheduler](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html) on Dataproc and set `queueMaxAppsDefault` property to 1.

Comment: I tried `fair scheduler` but still all jobs running parallel.

Comment: Try to set `yarn.scheduler.fair.user-as-default-queue` YARN property to `false`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43194378/3227693

Comment: May you share your fair scheduler configuration and init action that you use to configure it?

Comment: I also did this changes on all worker node and restart service but still it show same issue

Comment: How did you update these configuration files? May you share cluster creation command and init actions that you used?

Comment: You may want to try to follow these instructions to configure fair scheduler on Dataproc: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49693693/3227693

Comment: Thanks for this link, it works as charm !!!. But I have one issue in jobs dashboard jobs status show `running` but in detailed logs of jobs shows that it's in waiting state. Instead of this is possible to show on jobs dashboard status as `pending` for all incoming jobs ?

Comment: This is because from Dataproc point of view job is running (i.e. it was started and submitted to YARN), but YARN puts it in waiting state - Datparoc job status is a different thing than YARN job status and there no way to surface YARN job status in Dataproc jobs page.

Comment: Okay, got it Thanks for your help